# How to calculate the probability of hidden markov models?

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I've seen the great article from [Hidden Markov Model Simplified](https://medium.com/@postsanjay/hidden-markov-models-simplified-c3f58728caab).

In this article. I've been struggled at some point.

[image]

I understood the mathematical formulation of the joint probability.

But I cannot find the answer why the result of the calculation is 0.75.

Is there anyone to let me understand??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the calculation,

**STEP 1:**

P(A,B,A,Red,Green,Red) = [P(y_0=A) P(x_0=Red/y_0=A)] [P(y_1=B|y_0=A|)

P(x_1=Green/y_1=B)] [P(y_2=A|y_1=B) P(x_2=Red/y_2=A)]

**STEP 2**

=(1∗1)∗(1∗0.75)∗(1∗1)(1)(1)=(1∗1)∗(1∗0.75)∗(1∗1)

**STEP 3**

=0.75(1)(1)=0.75

INSTEAD OF 
=0.75(2)(2)=0.75

There is a typo in step 3, hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes. I've seen its calculation.

Comment: But I couldn't catch the idea where 0.75 numbers come from.

Comment: If you scroll down the article, the values have been picked up from the code below figure 12, but yes nowhere there is a calculation for 0.75